# which is the basis of T?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

let x,y be two independent vectors of $R^{2}$. let T:$R^{2}$→$R^2$ be a linear

transformation such that T(y)= cx and T(x)=0.then with respect to some basis matrix of T is

A) $\left[\begin{matrix}
        a  & 0 \\
        0 & a \\
        \end{matrix}
\right]$  where a>0

B)$\left[\begin{matrix}
        a  & 0 \\
        0 & b \\
        \end{matrix}
\right]$ where a ≠ b

C)$\left[\begin{matrix}
        0  & 1 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
\right]$

D)$\left[\begin{matrix}
        0  & 0 \\
        1 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
\right]$

my attempts : for linear  transformation T(x+y) = T(x) +T(y)= 0 + cx  = cx that is T(x+y) =T(y)..now i don't know from where i have to start ,,,im confused pliz help me and tell me the solution.....

Comment: Are you sure you have quoted the options right? Both C and D are possible.

Comment: Hint : $T^2 = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $\{x,y\}$ is $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&c\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Both the trace and the determinant of this matrix are $0$. So, that excludes options A) and B). Options C) and D) are both valid (assuming that $c\neq0$). Consider  the basis $\{cx,y\}$ and you get option C). Can you see why option D) is valid too?

Comment: The matrix of $T$ being what you say, how to explain
$$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&c\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)?$$

Comment: @Piquito $\displaystyle\begin{pmatrix}0&c\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}cx_2\\0\end{pmatrix}\neq\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: Then $T(x)\ne 0$ and $T(x)=0$?. Very cordially.

Comment: @Piquito With respect to the basis $\{x,y\}$, $x=\binom10$ and $y=\binom01$. Therefore$$\begin{pmatrix}0&c\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}\iff T(x)=0$$and$$\begin{pmatrix}0&c\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}c\\0\end{pmatrix}=c\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}\iff T(y)=cx.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm out of training in basic linear algebra for what I see.